# Php multidimensional array getting values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code sample

```
private $analyze_types = array(
    "1" => array(
        'level' => '4',
        'l1' => '-1',
        'l2' => '-1',
        'l3' => '-1',
        'l4' => '-1',
        'l5' => '-1'
    ),
    "226" => array(
        'level' => '-1',
        'l1' => '-1',
        'l2' => '-1',
        'l3' => '2',
        'l4' => '3',
        'l5' => '4'
    )
);
```

How can i get value of "1" and if I want to get 'level' value, what should i do?

Comment: Don't think I understand your question. Can you be more detailed?

Comment: Well, I have a protected function in the same class with this array. And I want to get 1 and 226 in this case.

Comment: @FreshPro: Are you looking for `array_keys` or something similar?

Comment: what's the criteria to fetch the result when you say you want to get 1 and 126?

Comment: Well I'll fetch results and I need 1 and 226 to compare if fld_type=1 or fld_type=226 exists in database and if not i will insert inner array values in database that's why i'm asking

Comment: It sounds a rather basic question. Just as other people suggested, either foreach or array_keys will do the trick. I just wonder what effort you have made to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP :

```
foreach( $this->analyze_types as $key => $value) {
  echo $key; // output 1 and 226
  echo $value['level']; // output 4 and -1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get element with index `'level'` of subarray with index `'1'` in main array you should use just

```
$this->analyze_types[1]['level']
```

Comment: @FreshPro So `array_keys($this->analyze_types)` as other people suggested

Answer (score 2):

You can try array_column (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

eg.:

```
$levels = array_column($this->analyze_types, 'level');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keys of an array by doing the following, if that's what you're asking?

```
$keys = array_keys($this->analyze_types);
print_r($keys);
```

Now that you have an array of keys you can simply loop through them to execute more code, for example:

```
foreach($keys as $k) {
    echo $k; //This will echo out 1
}
```