# PHP - find value comparing two multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've here two `multi-dimensional arrays`.

How would you do to get the `image_to_get` value in the $b array thanks to the $a array ?

```php
$a = array(
    'thumbs' => array(
        '0' => array(
            'thumb1a' => array(
                '0' => array(
                    'thumb1' => ""
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$b = array(
    'thumbs' => array(
        '0' => array(
            'thumb1a' => array(
                '0' => array(
                    'thumb1' => "image_to_get"
                )
            ),
            'thumb2' => 'image2',
            'thumb3' => 'image3',
            'thumb4' => 'image4',
            'thumb5' => 'image5',
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Is it always at a known depth, or do you have handle any level of nesting?

Comment: No it's not always at a known depth.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299137/php-multidimensional-array-getting-values Can you check this question? It seems related to yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
function getAPath($array) {
    if (empty($array)) {
        return array();
    }
    $key = key($array);

    return array_merge(array($key), getAPath($array[$key]));
}
function getBValue($array, $path) {
    $key = array_shift($path);

    if (is_null($key) || empty($array)) {
        return $array;
    }

    return getBValue($array[$key], $path);
}

$aPath  = getAPath($a);
$bValue = getBValue($b, $aPath);
var_dump($bValue);
```

First function `getAPath` flatterns your `$a` array into:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'thumbs' (length=6)
  1 => int 0
  2 => string 'thumb1a' (length=7)
  3 => int 0
  4 => string 'thumb1' (length=6)
```

Second function `getBValue` walks through the `$b` array using `$aPath`.

Below lovely one-liners ;-)

```
function getAPath($array) {
    return empty($array) ? array() : array_merge(array($key = key($array)), getAPath($array[$key]));
}
function getBValue($array, $path) {
    return (is_null($key = array_shift($path)) || empty($array)) ? $array :  getBValue($array[$key], $path);
}
```